# Integrate Processor in a browser?

Tags: browser, xquery

How to integrate Saxon-EE Processor in a web browser like IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension for IE and Firefox which integrates another XQuery engine (Zorba) in the browser (http://www.xqib.org). There will soon be a new release including Chrome, Safari and Opera as well.